# Full Background Image become clickable

Tags: html, css

I want to try full background become clickable. But It doesn't work at all.

Here is my HTML

```
<body>

<a href="home.php">
    <div id="clickable">
        <div id="context">
            <p> TESTING </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</a>

</body>
```

Here is my script for background to make it full background.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#background").ezBgResize({
            img : "assets/images/background.jpg",
            opacity : 1,
            center : true
        });
    });
</script>
```

Lastly, my CSS..

```
#clickable {
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    border:1px solid white; 
}
```

I really don't want to put height on `#clickable` because if I add something, the background image would be screwed. And the problem is I want to make the whole page become clickable but it doesn't work at all. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add `position: absolute;` to #clickable

```
#clickable {
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    border:1px solid white;
    position: absolute;
}
```

An example : http://jsfiddle.net/Mhba6/

Comment: ah I forgot to put `position:absolute`, was very careless. Thanks for solving!

Answer (score 3):

My approach:

http://jsfiddle.net/skozz/PyTVV/

**CSS:**

```
body {
    position: relative;
}
#background {
   position: absolute;
   z-index: 0;
}
#clickable {
    z-index: 1;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    border:1px solid white; 
    position: absolute;
    color: white;
}
```

**HMTL:**

```
<body>

    <div id="background">
        <a href="http://google.com"><img src="http://crispme.com/wp-content/uploads/3498.jpg?pass"></a>
    </div>

<a href="home.php">
    <div id="clickable">
        <div id="context">
            <p> TESTING </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</a>

</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, I don't want to put body because each page has different background picture. Anyway, it works well now. Cheers mate!

Answer (score 1):

`top` `left` and `right` values for CSS come into picture only if `position:relative` or `position:absolute`; is specified. Otherwise there is no point in adding these without adding the position attribute.

Further you have whole page content inside an a tag, a tag is an inline level element, you would want it to make a block level element by floating it using `float:left/right;` or simple adding `a{display:block;}`